# LINQ intersect, multiple lists, some empty

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find an intersect with LINQ.

Sample:

```
List<int> int1 = new List<int>() { 1,2 };
List<int> int2 = new List<int>();
List<int> int3 = new List<int>() { 1 };
List<int> int4 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
List<int> int5 = new List<int>() { 1 };
```

Want to return: 1 as it exists in all lists..  If I run:

```
var intResult= int1
            .Intersect(int2)
            .Intersect(int3)
            .Intersect(int4)
            .Intersect(int5).ToList();
```

It returns nothing as 1 obviously isn't in the int2 list.  How do I get this to work regardless if one list is empty or not ?

Use the above example or:

```
List<int> int1 = new List<int>() { 1,2 };
List<int> int2 = new List<int>();
List<int> int3 = new List<int>();
List<int> int4 = new List<int>();
List<int> int5 = new List<int>();
```

How do I return 1 & 2 in this case..  I don't know ahead of time if the lists are populated...

Comment: Consider the intersection of `{1}, {2}, {3}`. After intersecting the first two, you're then trying to find the intersection of `{}, {3}`. And you're asking for us to come up with something that will give `{}` in this case, but `{3}` if we performed the same operation on `{3}, {}`. If you don't want empty lists to be considered, then remove them from consideration before trying to work out the intersection.

Comment: @Anon, interesting observation.

Comment: How would I manage that???

if (int2.Count >0) var set = int1.Intersect(int2);
if (int3.Count >0) var set2 = set.Intersect(set);
if (int2.Count >0) var set3 = int2.Intersect(int2);
.....

Seems kinda hokey...

Comment: the point that he makes is that the intersection of {1} and {2} is an empty list, so the intersection of *that* with {3} is {3}. That's a pitfall of allowing empty sets to be ignored by an Intersect method, as empty *results* get ignored as well as you chain the methods.

Comment: That's the question then... Isn't there some way to ignore empty sets without checking to see if they are empty?

Answer (score 16):

If you need it in a single step, the simplest solution is to filter out empty lists:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectNonEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> lists)
{
    var nonEmptyLists = lists.Where(l => l.Any());
    return nonEmptyLists.Aggregate((l1, l2) => l1.Intersect(l2));
}
```

You can then use it on a collection of lists or other `IEnumerable`s:

```
IEnumerable<int>[] lists = new[] { l1, l2, l3, l4, l5 };
var intersect = lists.IntersectNonEmpty();
```

You may prefer a regular static method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectNonEmpty<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
{
    return lists.IntersectNonEmpty();
}

var intersect = ListsExtensionMethods.IntersectNonEmpty(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5);
```

Comment: Just a minor warning: thanks to the Aggregate(), this extension method will throw an InvalidOperationException with "sequence contains no elements" if all of the lists are empty.

Answer (score 2):

You could write an extension method to define that behaviour. Something like

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectAllIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        if (other.Any())
            return list.Intersect(other);
        else
            return list;
    }
}
```

So the code below would print 1.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
List<int> list3 = new List<int>() { 1 };

foreach (int i in list1.IntersectAllIfEmpty(list2).IntersectAllIfEmpty(list3))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

**Update:**

Anon brings up a good point in the comments to the question. The above function *will* result in an empty set if `list` itself is empty, which should be desirable. This means if the first list in the method chain *or* the result set of any intersection is empty, the final result will be empty.

To allow for an empty first list *but* not for empty result sets, you could take a different approach. This is a method which is not an extension method, but rather takes a params array of IEnumerables and first filters out the empty sets and then attempts to intersect the rest.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectAllIfEmpty<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
{
    IEnumerable<T> results = null;

    lists = lists.Where(l => l.Any()).ToArray();

    if (lists.Length > 0)
    {
        results = lists[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < lists.Length; i++)
            results = results.Intersect(lists[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        results = new T[0];
    }

    return results;
}
```

You would use it like this

```
List<int> list0 = new List<int>();
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 1 };
List<int> list3 = new List<int>() { 1,2,3 };

foreach (int i in IntersectAllIfEmpty(list0, list1, list2, list3))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: where would I declare the extension method?  Gives me: Extension method can only be decalred in non-generic, non-nested static class

just trying to do this in a method..

Comment: You would put that in a static class. I've added the a class definition to my answer.