# join unknown number of lists in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation where I have generated a number of lists which contain integer values. However, the number of these lists is **only known at runtime**, and integers present in the resulting list must exist in all lists. Is there a method of joining all of these lists into a single list?

i.e.

```
List<int> l1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
List<int> l2 = {2, 3, 5, 7, 9};
List<int> l3 = {3, 9, 10};
List<int> ln = {....};
```

The resulting list should be as follows

```
List<int> r = {3};
```

Is this possible with linq or any other methods?

Comment: Are the lists in an array or a list or similar? You've shown them being defined at compile time, which doesn't agree with your question...

Comment: Also, does it have to be done in LINQ?  Is this something where you are trying to avoid the records being pulled back from a DB or are the results being processed in memory on the local system?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191810/linq-intersect-multiple-lists-some-empty for similar question.

Comment: Ken, where you get those lists from?

Comment: Each list is comprised of a sequence of primary keys returned from a either a UDF or another system. This is the reason it's not all done on the DB. The number of querys run is variable so the number of lists is only know after all results are found

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you have a `List<List<int>>` that holds a variable number of `List<int>`.

You can [intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) the first list with the second list

```
var intersection = listOfLists[0].Intersect(listOfLists[1]);
```

and then intersect the result with the third list

```
intersection = intersection.Intersect(listOfLists[2]);
```

and so on until `intersection` holds the intersection of all lists.

```
intersection = intersection.Intersect(listOfLists[listOfLists.Count - 1]);
```

Using a `for` loop:

```
IEnumerable<int> intersection = listOfLists[0];

for (int i = 1; i < listOfLists.Count; i++)
{
    intersection = intersection.Intersect(listOfLists[i]);
}
```

Using a `foreach` loop (as shown by *@lazyberezovsky*):

```
IEnumerable<int> intersection = listOfLists.First();

foreach (List<int> list in listOfLists.Skip(1))
{
    intersection = intersection.Intersect(list);
}
```

Using [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx):

```
var intersection = listOfLists.Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect);
```

---

If order is not important, then you can also use a [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) that you fill with the first list and [intersect with](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx) with the remaining lists (as shown by *@Servy*).

```
var intersection = new HashSet<int>(listOfLists.First());

foreach (List<int> list in listOfLists.Skip(1))
{
    intersection.IntersectWith(list);
}
```

Comment: While all is true, this doesn't answer the (unclear) "however the number of these lists is only known at runtime" part of the question

Comment: It should be fairly easy to keep the intersection variable outside the loop, then you can (presumably) iterate through the lists - edit: as per lazyberezovsky's answer

Comment: I like the `Aggregate` version.

Comment: Thanks for the info will give this a try first thing in the morning

Answer (score 1):

```
// lists is a sequence of all lists from l1 to ln
if (!lists.Any())
   return new List<int>();

IEnumerable<int> r = lists.First();   

foreach(List<int> list in lists.Skip(1))    
   r = r.Intersect(list);

return r.ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the (unclear) "however the number of these lists is only known at runtime" part of the question

Comment: @ken2k that's because it's unclear from question how those lists are retrieved. I believe OP can enumerate over them, but I'll add a comment to question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method to get the intersection of a collection of collections:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Intersect<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    using (var iterator = sequences.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>();

        HashSet<T> intersection = new HashSet<T>(iterator.Current);

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
            intersection.IntersectWith(iterator.Current);

        return intersection;
    }
}
```

The idea here is to put all of the items into a set, then intersect that set with each sequence in turn.  We can do this with a lot less code using plain LINQ, but this will be populating a new `HashSet` from the results for each intersection, rather than reusing a single one, so it will have a lot higher overhead despite looking really elegant.

Here is the less performant but more elegant solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Intersect<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    return sequences.Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect);
}
```