# algorithm to consolidate overlapping range

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I have an offer configured with discount values and applicable volume range.

Its possible multiple offers applicable for a product, so I am looking for algorithm to consolidate overlapping volume range among various offers and show final discount applicable. Below code snippet would help to visualize the ask :

```
class VolumeTierRange
    {
        public int Min { get; set; }
        public int Max { get; set; }
        public int Discount { get; set; }
    } 

/* Offer1Range */
    List<VolumeTierRange> Offer1Ranges = new List<VolumeTierRange>{
                        new VolumeTierRange {Min=1,   Max=20,   Discount=2 },
                        new VolumeTierRange {Min=21,  Max=49 ,  Discount=10 },
                        new VolumeTierRange {Min=50,  Max=100 , Discount=5 },
                        new VolumeTierRange {Min=101, Max=1000, Discount=15}
                    };

/* Offer2Range */
List<VolumeTierRange> dicountBRanges = new List<VolumeTierRange>{
                new VolumeTierRange {Min = 1, Max=50,   Discount=6},
                new VolumeTierRange {Min=51,  Max=1000, Discount=10 }
            };
```

Consolidated result would look like :

```
List<VolumeTierRange> effectiveDiscount = new List<VolumeTierRange>{
                new VolumeTierRange {Min=1,  Max=20,  Discount=8 },
                new VolumeTierRange {Min=21, Max=49,  Discount=16},
                new VolumeTierRange {Min=50, Max=50,  Discount=11},
                new VolumeTierRange {Min=51, Max=100, Discount=15},
                new VolumeTierRange {Min=101,Max=1000,Discount=25}
            };
```

I do have some ways to achieve the expected outcome, but those all does not seems to be very intuitive.

**Additional Info:** Min value of first item and Max value of all offers is fixed (like 1 and 1000 in this example). Also there cannot be discontinuity while defining volume range.

Comment: "I do have some ways to achieve the expected outcome" You should *show* what you´ve tried, in order to avoid anybody oisting the same solution you already have.

Comment: So you need to intersect integer ranges and add a couple of discounts up. What's stopping you?

Comment: Why discount in last consolidated row is 15 and not 25?

Comment: Yes. It's possible

Comment: @Evk : corrected.

Comment: @HimBromBeere : I can post what i tried but its going to clutter code and overall ask. Its nothing fancy : I did sorting on range min and max values and then tried to create chunk of overlapping ranges. Also its failing certain edge case scenarios, hence posted here.

Comment: Then those failing edge-cases are of upmost interest. How would you know if *any* of the solutions  matches thoses cases where you failed? How should *we* know what works for you and what not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first thing you want to do is figure out what values in `Offer1Ranges` overlap what values in `dicountBRanges`.
Items overlap when the min value of the first item is less then (or equal*) to the max value of the second item, while the min value of the second item is less then (or equal*) to the max value of the first item. For more information, see the [overlap](/questions/tagged/overlap) tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info).

Once you've joined the lists based on the overlapping items, it's a simple enough select to get the biggest of the two min values, the smallest of the two max values, and the sum of the discount value for each item:

```
var query = from o in Offer1Ranges
            from d in dicountBRanges
            where o.Min <= d.Max
            && o.Max >= d.Min
            select new VolumeTierRange()
            {
                Min = (o.Min > d.Min) ? o.Min : d.Min,
                Max = (o.Max < d.Max) ? o.Max : d.Max,
                Discount = o.Discount + d.Discount
            };
```

[You can see a live demo or rextester.](http://rextester.com/PALPR23185)

---

*In your case, you consider the items overlapping even if it's on a single point (min of first equals the max of second or vice versa). This is not the general case.

**Please note:** This solution will only work as long as both lists starts and ends in the same numbers, and there are no gaps, as stated in the question:

> "**Additional Info:** Min value of first item and Max value of all offers is fixed (like 1 and 1000 in this example). Also there cannot be discontinuity while defining volume range."

Comment: Thanks !! This looks cleaner. Can this be modified to not limit to only two specific offer ranges. I can have any numbers of offer applicable for product.

Comment: Probably... [check this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984879/join-unknown-number-of-lists-in-linq)